# Can I limit remote desktop to a particular network card?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

I have two routers/internet connections connected to my PC. One is a slower connection with a fixed IP that I use for business, the other is a faster connection I use for day to day surfing. I have to use the fixed IP connection to log onto certain servers (due to security) to work but I'm finding that often my PC will try to use my other internet connection to connect which will get rejected (as it doesn't have the fixed IP). Can I limit remote desktop to use a particular network card to get around this problem.

Note: I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can limit the RDP protocol itself to a single NIC, but you can manipulate all traffic leaving your machine to a specific IP address to use a specific NIC.  The command required is `route` which is used via CMD.

[Here's a how-to](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/25/how-to-add-route-to-tcpip-routing-table-with-windows-routing-and-remote-access-console-or-dos-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

Not RDP specifically but you could create a static route so that all traffic from your machine to the particular server going over a particular interface - use the 'route' command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in XP, and i'm lmost sure something like this will also be available for Win7. 
[microsoft kb:924927](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924927)

Hope this helps.
Kamaradski

Comment: This KB article is actually for the _inbound_ case; the question was about how to make _outbound_ Remote Desktop connections via a particular network card.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you have two separate interfaces both with a default gateway.

Traffic destined for remote/not directly routed networks won't know which interface to go through when both have default routes/gateways, so Windows will just pick one of them and stick with it (generally the last interface to come online).

To solve this, remove the default gateway on the interface you use the least and add static routes for that interface for the remote networks and/or IP addresses that has to go over it.

In general, Windows clients wants only one default gateway - which I think makes sense. Your setup seems to circumvent some parts of the security setup in having control over the endpoint (your fixed IP) by allowing you to multi-home the client over another un-controlled endpoint at the same time - creating the possibility for malware to route traffic via your client into the corporate network.

A simple solution is for you to unplug/plug/enable/disable the connections so only one is actually enabled at any one time (could be scripted).